# cite with new style

Tags: bibtex, citing

I want to References be cited in the text by number within square brackets and listed at the end of the paper in the order in which they appear in the text.  References should be listed in the following style:

1. Dower PM, James MR. Dissipativity and nonlinear systems with finite power gain. International Journal of Robust and Nonlinear Control 1998; 8 (8): 699-724. DOI:10.1002/rnc.344
2. Liu GP, Patton RJ. Eigenstructure Assignment for Control System Design. Wiley: Chichester, 1998;1-22.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\LaTeX{} \cite{texbook1} is a set of macros built atop \cite{texbook2}.
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
    \bibitem{texbook1} Dower PM, James MR. Dissipativity and nonlinear systems with finite power gain. International Journal of Robust and Nonlinear Control 1998; 8 (8):699-724.DOI:10.1002/rnc.344
    \bibitem{texbook2}Liu GP, Patton RJ. Eigenstructure Assignment for Control System Design. Wiley: Chichester, 1998;1-22.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I want to use BibTeX.

Comment: https://fr.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Bibliography_management_with_bibtex here is your answer